# Express redirect route to another route

Tags: node.js, express

If user requests for get request on `/user` it should execute route this `/api/user` like we do for static files.
user requests for `https://example.com/user`then it should execute below code

```
app.get('/api/user', (req,res,next) => {
    Do Something
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can approach this in different ways.

**Solution #1**

```
app.get('/user', (req, res, next) => {
   res.redirect(307, '/api/user');
});

app.get('/api/user', (req,res,next) => {
   // Your business logic...
});
```

**Solution #2**

```
app.get('/user', (req, res, next) => {
   req.url = '/api/user';
   next();
});

app.get('/api/user', (req,res,next) => {
   // Your business logic...
});
```

Comment: can we use params.. like redirecting `/user/:xyz/:abc` to `/user/api/:xyz/:abc`
Actually I am implementing email verification and its link is `http://example.com/verify/:id/:token` which I want to accept at `http://example.com/api/user/verify/:id/:token`

Comment: Yes, just extract them and append at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to another route by using res.redirect:

```
app.get('/user',(req,res)=>{
   res.redirect('/api/user');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider registering the same router code with two different routes.

```
const apiRouter = express.Router()
apiRouter.post('/', function (req, res, next) { ... }

app.use('/user', apiRouter)
app.use('/api/user', apiRouter)
```

If your route methods use route parameters (you call them "tokens") they should work correctly.

You didn't ask about this. But don't put secrets in routes, because URLs get logged to web server logs.  For example `https://bank.example.com/12345/password/` is a bad idea. Put your users' secrets in POST body parameters instead.  (Proxy servers keep logs as well as your own servers.)  If the secret is a hard-to-guess one-time-use token it doesn't matter.

But, it's probably best to decide which route is the "official" one, then deprecate the other, then do a [308 permanent redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308) from the deprecated one to the official one. For example,

```
app.use('/user', (req,res,next) => {res.redirect(308,'/api/user})
```

Comment: can we use params.. like redirecting `/user/:xyz/:abc` to `/user/api/:xyz/:abc` Actually I am implementing email verification and its link is `http://example.com/verify/:id/:token` which I want to accept at `http://example.com/api/user/verify/:id/:token`

Comment: I am not passing any sensitive information just a user id and jwt token to verify a email